# How to setup nist nbis in raspbian raspberry pi 4

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi4, fingerprint, pi

I tried installing the NIST NBIS and followed the procedures inside the REL folder but I kept on getting error.

I tried the step by step command
[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sua9z.png)

But I always get this error on my raspberry pi in step 2,

> cmake config

```
gcc: unrecognized command line option '-m32'
```

Do you guys know what the problem is? Thank you.